# Java. Почему нельзя изменить ссылку на объект в методе?

Tags: java, ссылки, объекты, теория, параметры

Мой педагог задал мне задание ответить на ряд вопросов. И два их них меня сильно смущают.

> 1. Почему нельзя изменить ссылку на объект в методе?

Не могу понять смысл вопроса(((

> 2. Как в Java передаются параметры в методы?

Я гуглил этот вопрос и понял что по всегда по значению но что точно это значит не понял.

Не могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться в этой ситуации.

Comment: Поменяйте педагога! Скажите, что это вы должны ему задавать вопросы, а не он вам.:)

Comment: Да нет это что-то вроде устного зачета. Я должен был разобраться. У меня хороший педагог, не надо пожалуйста его обижать. ))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Почему нельзя изменить ссылку на объект в методе?

Потому что в метод передается **не ссылка**, **а объект**, который содержит **копию ссылки**.

> Как в Java передаются параметры в методы?

Все аргументы (как примитивные типы, так и объекты) в Java передаются при вызове **по значению**. Тут сразу стоит оговориться, что объект по сути представляет ссылку, следовательно, при изменении объекта в методе, изменится и исходный объект.

---

*Подробнее можно почитать в «Подробное рассмотрение особенностей передачи аргументов» в [полном руководстве](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/) по Java авторства Герберта Шилдта.*

Comment: >>>Почему нельзя изменить ссылку на объект в методе?
Потому что в метод передается копия объекта (которая ссылается туда же, куда и ссылался исходный объект).<<<

Comment: вот спасибо это помогло!

Comment: А зачем тогда оригинал, только память загромождать? Извините если глупость спрашиваю.

Comment: @Павел, Это скорее вопрос к разработчикам языка :) Да и к тому же, оба объекта будут ссылаться на одну и ту же область памяти.

Comment: Я все понял значит мне это и не надо знать). Спасибо за ответ. Удачи.

Comment: "в метод передается копия объекта " - Странное утверждение. Копия объекта (с оговорками) создается вообще-то методом clone(), а в метод передается копия ссылки на объект.

Comment: @m.vokhm, Я это и имел ввиду. Спасибо, выразился яснее.

Comment: @post_zeew вы бы хоть писали явно, что сделали update ответа.

Comment: @Roxio0, Зачем? Я написал «Спасибо, выразился яснее» и считаю, что этого вполне достаточно.

Comment: @post_zeew мне кажется, что ответ "в метод передаётся копия объекта" (как было написано изначально) имеет абсолютно другой смысл. Хотя, наверное, это всего лишь мои придирки.

Comment: @Roxio0, Дальше по тексту шло уточнение. Первоначально было сказано ровно то, что сказано сейчас, но иными словами. Сейчас просто формулировка более строгая.

Comment: @post_zeew простите, не заметил, вы опять поменяли ответ.

Comment: Сдается мне, что вы написали какую-то ерунду. В метод паредаются честные ссылки, которые могу изменять объект. Я не знаю от чего вы отталкивались вообще, в `C++` есть конструктор копирования, но это совсем другое...

Comment: @faoxis, Передача ссылок в метод происходит при передаче **параметров по ссылке**, однако в Java **все** параметры передаются при **вызове по значению** (но тут стоит заметить, что объекты в Java по сути представляют ссылки, то есть передается **копия** ссылки). Вопрос «Почему нельзя изменить ссылку на объект в методе?» я интерпретировал как «Почему, если в методе объект станет ссылаться в другое место, то исходный объект будет ссылаться туда же?», на него и отвечал.

Answer (score 8):

Как намекнул Vlad from Moscow в комментарии к вопросу, вопрос довольно странный, и на мой взгляд он не вполне корректен -- либо ваш преподаватель не очень хорошо умеет выражать свои мысли, либо вы как-то слегка исказили его вопрос.

Дело в том, что в методе менять ссылку вообще-то можно. Строго говоря, в Jave обычно говорят не о ссылках на объект, а о переменных (полях, аргументах) объектного типа. Но фактически значением таких переменных являются ссылки на объекты. Методы в качестве своих аргументов получают копии этих ссылок и могут делать с ними что хотят (т. е. присваивать им значения ссылок на другие объекты или null - "пустую ссылку"), что никак не отражается на значениях переменных, которые были переданы методу при его вызове. Так что вот такой код

```
public class TestQQ {

  static void qq(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    s = "Что-то новое..."; // Это ссылка или не ссылка меняется ? 
    System.out.println(s);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   String string = "Нельзя менять ссылки?";
   qq(string);
   System.out.println(string);
 } 
}
```

1. Создает новый объект класса String со значением "Нельзя менять ссылки?";
2. Присваивает ссылку на него переменной string;
3. Вызывает метод qq() и передает ему копию переменной string (т. е. создает вторую ссылку на ту же строку "Нельзя менять ссылки?")
4. Метод qq() выводит на консоль содержимое того объекта, ссылка на который содержится в его параметре - т. е. то же самое "нельзя?";
5. Метод qq() своему параметру s присваивает новое значение - ссылку на новую строку "Что-то новое...",  -- вторая ссылка на "нельзя" исчезает, но исходная переменная string в главной программе при этом никак не меняется и по-прежнему содержит ссылку на то же самое изначальное "нельзя?";
6. Метод qq() печатает новую строку ("Что-то новое...") и возвращает управление в главную программу (метод main);
7. Метод main() печатает содержимое объекта, который содержится (т. е. ссылка на который содержится) в переменной string - это по-прежнему изначальная строка "Нельзя менять ссылки?"

Вывод будет такой:`Нельзя менять ссылки?
Что-то новое
Нельзя менять ссылки?`

Но при этом надо отчетливо понимать, что хотя метод не может изменить значение объектной переменной, переданной ему в качестве параметра (т. е. ссылку на объект), он за милую душу может изменить сам объект! Например, в такой программе 

`import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestQQQ {
  static void qqq(ArrayList list) {
    list.add("можно.");
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();
   strings.add("А объекты менять...?");
   qqq(strings);
   System.out.println(strings);
 } 
}`

метод qqq() добавляет в список, ссылку на который он получил, новую строку "можно.",  и в результате мы получаем на выходе вот что:
`[А объекты менять...?, можно.]`

Comment: Вы очень развернуто объяснили спасибо большое тут есть над чем подумать, и если я все правильно понял то вы никак не противоречите ответу post_zeew о том что в метод передается копия ссылки. Конечно сами объекты менять можно иначе смысл создания самого метода потерялся бы ведь метод зачастую для этого и создается. Или все таки противоречие есть? Теперь я буду думать копия ссылки все таки передается в метод или оригинал? Что скажете?

Comment: В метод передается копия ссылки. Противоречия, видимо, нет; просто в первом варианте ответа он не вполне точно выразился. Потом исправил и стало лучше, а сейчас, я гляжу, снова исправил, и опять трудно понять, что он имеет в виду. Чтобы снять все сомнения, скопируйте мой код и поиграйтесь с ним - сами всё поймёте.

Comment: Да все понятно.

Answer (score 4):

> Почему нельзя изменить ссылку на объект в методе?

При передаче объекта в метод происходит просто копирование ссылки на него (Никаких копий объекта не создаётся при передачи!). И уже с помощью неё вы общаетесь с исходным объектом. Отсюда должно быть понятно, почему при перезаписывании в эту ссылку нового объекта старый не меняется. Простой пример для разъяснения:

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); //Создаём объект и кладём в ссылку
List<Object> list2 = list1; //Просто копируем ссылку
list2.add(new Object); //Через копию ссылки мы меняем исходный объект в list1
list2 = new ArrayList<>(); //Хоть мы и переписали в ссылку новый объект, 
//исходный никуда не делся, он всё также лежит в list1.
```

> Как в Java передаются параметры в методы?

Примитивы по значению, объекты - как я описал выше (не знаю как правильно называется этот способ).

**Update:** спасибо [@Roman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581880/java-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5/582055#comment775043_582055), правильное название способа передачи объектов в метод - [вызов по соиспользованию (call by sharing)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.92.D1.8B.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D0.BF.D0.BE_.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8E_.28call_by_sharing.29)

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, это формально называется по-прежнему передачей по значению, но при этом оговаривается, что значением объектной переменной является ссылка на объект, так что при вызове метода возникает вторая ссылка. Это важно понимать, когда дело касается сборки мусора и подобных вещей.

Comment: Спасибо кажется теперь я окончательно все понял!

Comment: Википедия говорит, что этот способ называется "[вызов по соиспользованию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.92.D1.8B.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D0.BF.D0.BE_.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8E_.28call_by_sharing.29)" (звучит как-то не очень, да).

Comment: @Roman, спасибо за ссылку! Пригодится - новичкам показывать :)